# Where are Google App Engine's Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, cloud, endpoint

I'm working on a project which uses the  Google App Engine to store application data remotely. So far, I've created a simple class `GenericEntity` and used Google's tools to generate a supporting Cloud Endpoint.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class GenericEntity {

/* Define the UniqueID as persistent and unique. Allow JDO to assign the value of UniqueId when uploaded with a null id. */
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long mUniqueId; // Value must be 'Long' and not a primitive 'long'!

@Persistent
private String mData;
[...]
```

I can also successfully create and delete instances of `GenericEntity` in the `GenericEntityEndpoint` using the API Explorer.

Request:

```
POST 

Content-Type:  application/json
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
"data": "hello SO!"
}
```

Response:

```
200 OK
```

The issue is that I would like to control these endpoints from a local Desktop application, but I'm confused as to how this is supposed to be done. I imagine that the `PersistenceManagerFactory` is local only to Google's servers, and subsequently can't be accessed directly by my application. Is there a final step I'm missing which will allow high-level interaction with these generated Endpoints over a network, or do I need to implement my own interface with the server using `HttpUrlRequest` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud endpoint sends JSON data using REST or RPC over HTTP and authentication is managed using OAuth2 so you can either write your desktop application from scratch or you can use the various Google libraries to connect to your endpoint. For Java applications I usually use the Android cloud endpoint library which you can generate using the endpoint.sh, I use the classes generated for Android to call the cloud endpoint from any other Java apps:

```
appengine-java-sdk-x.x.x/bin/endpoints.sh <command> <options> [class-name]
```

more details here (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool)

Once the source jar is generated by endpoint.sh I usually expand it into my client Java project. Otherwise you can compile the generated classes and bundle them as a binary jar. Once this is done you need to take care of the authentication part. This can be done by using the OAuth2 Java client library (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/oauth2/v1) see the provided example **[oauth2-cmdline-sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/oauth2-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/oauth2/cmdline/OAuth2Sample.java?repo=samples)**

Once you have an OAuth2 token calling the cloud endpoint form your desktop application is no different to calling any other Google API, the Service Object and Builder patterns are all the same e.g. depending on the name of your endpoint API you can create a service object from the endpoint.sh generated classes as follows

```
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredential()).build();
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed and informative answer. I'm going to install the Android Device Tools (ADT) plugin for Eclipse, alongside it's dependencies, and hopefully this will allow me to generate the client API within my existing project as you have recommended.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are not developing for Android you do not need to install the ADT, the commandline tool endpoint.sh generate Java classes which you can use in any Java application, so you can use these files in your normal Eclipse